# Gtk3 textView does not display entire file (of a certain size) - last lines are invisible

Tags: c++, gtk, gdk

Gtk3 textView does not display entire file (of a certain size) - last lines are invisible.

The demo code was abstracted from an app I am developing. All error handling code, extraneous widgets etc. removed.

Loading the sample file "zs.txt" - only the first 965 lines are displayed visibly

- the last few lines are marked with the line number (961 to 970). Only lines up to 965 are displayed.
- the remaining lines ARE in the buffer, but are invisible.
- The demo code reads-back the buffer and saves it in "zback.txt", which compares identically with "zs.txt".

Weirdly, loading the file "zs_big.txt", which is twice the size of "zs.txt"`, loads 
OK, all the lines are visible.

I have tried

- forcibly changing the visibility through tags - no effect.
- switching between the following gave no improvement:

  - gtk_text_buffer_set_text()
  - gtk_text_buffer_insert() - in one go, and looping over small chunks
  - gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor()

It appears to be largely sensitive to the number of lines in the file, but there also seems
to be some data sensitivity (i.e. line length) as well.

I really cannot see a reason for this behavior. Any help greatly appreciated!

g.cpp g.h  - graphic code.

zs.txt     - small file that invokes problem.

zs_big.txt - big file that works ok.

The widget hierarchy is:

```
m_win           - main window
  |
  m_vbox        - vertical box
    |
    m_hPane     - horizontal pane
      |
      m_vScrWin - scrolled window
        |   
        m_vSub  - sub box
          |
          m_aTV - application textView
```

Running on ubuntu trusty 14.04.6 LTS.

To build:
  make

Uses g++, with

- gtk+-3.0
- x11
- gdk-x11-2.0
- Xt

Executable is then simply: g

g.cpp:

```
#include "g.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "g.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,  char **argv)
{
    CG *g = new CG;
    g->gui(argc,  argv);
    delete g;
    return(0);
}

CG::CG(){};

void CG::gui(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //SELECT FILE TO LOAD
    m_file = (char *)"zs.txt";
    //m_file = (char *)"zs_big.txt";

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // Main window
    m_win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(m_win),  0,  0);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(m_win), 600, 800);

    // vertical box in main window
    m_vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(m_win), m_vbox); 

    // Horizontal pane in vertical box
    m_hPane = gtk_paned_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(m_hPane, 500, 200);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(m_vbox), m_hPane, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    // Scrolled window in horizontal pane
    m_vScrWin = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(m_vScrWin), GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);
    gdk_cursor_new(GDK_XTERM);
    gtk_widget_get_window(m_vScrWin);
    gtk_paned_pack1(GTK_PANED(m_hPane), m_vScrWin, TRUE, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_realize(m_vScrWin);

    // Vertical sub-box in scrolled window
    m_vSub  = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(m_vSub, 40, 20);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(m_vScrWin), m_vSub); 

    // Application text view in vertical sub-box
    m_aTV = gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_text_view_set_editable(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(m_aTV), FALSE);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(m_vSub ), m_aTV, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show_all(m_win);

    GtkTextBuffer *textViewBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(m_aTV));
    writeTextToView(m_file, textViewBuffer);
    save(textViewBuffer);
    gtk_main();
}

void CG::writeTextToView(const gchar *const fname,  GtkTextBuffer *textViewBuffer)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fileno(fp), &st);

    gchar *rbuf = new gchar[st.st_size];
    fread(rbuf, 1, st.st_size, fp);

    fclose(fp);
        // Have also tried gtk_text_buffer_insert() gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor() here.
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(textViewBuffer, rbuf, st.st_size);

    delete [] rbuf; 
}

void
CG::save(GtkTextBuffer *textViewBuffer)
{
    GtkTextIter sIter, eIter;
    gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(textViewBuffer, &sIter);
    gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(textViewBuffer, &eIter);

    gchar *cp = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(textViewBuffer, &sIter, &eIter, TRUE);

    FILE *fp = fopen("zback.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", cp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

g.h:

```
#ifndef GRAPHIC_H
#define GRAPHIC_H
#include "g.h"
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class CG
{
public:
    CG();
    ~CG(){};
    void gui(int argc, char *argv[]);
    void LoadInitialFiles();
    void writeTextToView(const gchar *const ptr, GtkTextBuffer *tvb);
    void save(GtkTextBuffer *textViewBuffer);
    gchar *m_file;
    GtkWidget *m_hPane;
    GtkWidget *m_vScrWin;
    GtkWidget *m_win;
    GtkWidget *m_vbox;
    GtkWidget *m_vSub;
    GtkWidget *m_aTV;
};
#endif
```

makefile:

```
    GCCFLAGS= -g -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 

all: tags g 

g: g.o
    g++ $(GCCFLAGS) -o g g.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 x11 gdk-x11-2.0` -lXt  -I/usr/include/X11

g.o: g.cpp g.h
    g++ $(GCCFLAGS) -c g.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 x11 gdk-x11-2.0` -I/usr/include/X11 

clean: 
    rm -f g *.o tags zback.txt

tags: *.h *.cpp
    ctags *.h *.cpp
```

zs.txt (small data sample file that fails):

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx

xx
xx
xx
xxxx
xx
x
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
x
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xxx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx
xxx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx
xxx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xxx
xx
xx
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
x
xx
x

xx
xx
xx
xxx
xx
x
xx
x

xxx
xx
xx
xxx
xxxx
xx
x
xx
xx
x

xxx
xx
xx
xxx
xxxx
xx
x
xx
xx
xxx
xx
xxx
xxxxxx
xxx
xx
xxx
xx
x

xx

xx
xx
x
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xxxxxx
x

xx
xx
xx

file xx
file xx

file xx

file xx
file xx
file xx
file xx
file xx
file xx

file xx
file xx

file xx
file xx

file xx

line 961 xx
line 962 xx
line 963 xx
line 964 xx
line 965 xx
line 966 xx
line 967 xx
line 968 xx
line 969 xx
line 970 xx
```

zs_big.txt (big sample file that works):

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

line 963 xx
line 964 xx
line 965 xx
line 966 xx
line 967 xx
xx

xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx


xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx


xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx


xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx

xx


xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx

xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx

xx
xx

line 963 xx
line 964 xx
line 965 xx

line 966 xx
line 967 xx
xx

xx

xx

xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx


xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx


xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx


xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx

xx
line 2998 and lastxx
```

Comment: The important detail is surely the contents of the file.

Comment: The contents of the data files is pure ascii - no special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here. Gnome-Shell on X11, Arch Linux, Gtk 3.24.12

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. So its beginning to sound like a library version problem.